# BroadcastReceiver and FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES

Tags: java, android

Good afternoon !

I am completely confused: When the phone restarts, the receiver should start the service. Has the application never started? Where to put this flag?

BootBroadcast.java:

```
package by.minsk.davydov.checkcell;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BootBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast Intent Detected !",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        context.startService(new Intent(context, check.class));
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name=".BootBroadcast" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name=".check"/>
</application>
```

check.java:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class check extends Service {
    final String TAG = "myLogs";
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "Start check !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("by.minsk.davydov.checkcell");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    } // arg0
}
```

Comment: You don't/can't put that flag. The system would have to do that. Since Android 3.1, you can't really have an app without a launcher `Activity`. Your app is installed in a _stopped_ state, and won't be delivered that broadcast until some component in your app has been explicitly started. The only way for most apps to get started is through their main `Activity`.

Comment: but what about <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/> ?

Comment: That's the broadcast I was talking about. Sorry, I should have been more clear. Your app won't be delivered that `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast until it's been moved out of the _stopped_ state, which won't happen until it's been launched by the user. That is, basically, your app can't automatically launch at boot until the user has run it once.

Comment: but i want to use intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);

Comment: You can't. You're not sending that `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast. The system is sending it, and it would have to be the one to add that flag.

Comment: Ok, the application started (a message appeared in the logs), but after rebooting the phone, there is nothing in the logs!

Answer (score 0):

change receiver in manifest to this:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".BootBroadcast"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Your app **needs to run once** (at least) after installing to receive boot notifications

The intent is sent to you by Android and you do not have a choice to say what bundles want to have in this intent.

Comment: I have an application installed, but the launcher does not see it. How do I run it?

Comment: @Davydov Add an activity ( right click your package and add an activity) tick launcher activity in wizard

Comment: Ok, the application started (a message appeared in the logs), but after rebooting the phone, there is nothing in the logs!